# Set style and text of a jTextPane using a StyledDocument

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, styleddocument

I'm creating a basic Swing applcation. I have *jTextPane* and a button. If the user selects text in the *jTextPane* and presses the button, it bolds the selected text. This is done by modifying the *StyleDocument*.

I want to be able to save the styled text temporarily, close the previous *jTextPane*, open up a new *jTextPane*, and populate it based off the previous saved styled text. *jTextPane* takes a *StyleDocument* in the constructor, but when I try to construct a new jTextPane with the old *StyleDocument*, it doesn't appear to be working. I figure it's because I'm just passing in the reference from the previous jTextPane StyleDocument which is eventually removed.

Is there any way to copy or clone a StyleDocument? I understand it's an interface, but is it using a DefaultStyledDocument? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document could be replaced with a new instance e.g. when you set EditorKit or call setText() (setText recreates document in some cases).

So when you store the referece to the old Document call setDocument(oldDoc) after all preparations are done.

Or you can store old content and set it back using something like this http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial.html

Read about Reader and Writer and use code from the "Example" section.

Comment: +1 `(setText recreates document in some cases)` Stas please then `Document` can by cloned e.g. `Document myNewDocument = oldDocument` or is there something else ???

Comment: When setText is called we don't need content of the old Document. So Just a new instance is created. The only thing is to moving DocumentListeners and properties.

Comment: "Document could be replaced with a new instance" What do you mean by this?

Comment: And what is the difference between a Document and a StyledDocument?